# Problema a la hora de ejecutar una consulta SQL por PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Estoy intentando agregando datos con insert into select a una tabla desde php pero no me esta haciendo caso. Cuando hago un `echo $consulta`; me muestra esto:

```
INSERT INTO orden_requisitos SELECT NIA, COUNT(*) AS Total FROM alumnos_formacion inner join oferta_formacion ON alumnos_formacion.idFormacion=oferta_formacion.idFormacion WHERE idOferta=1 GROUP BY NIA ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

Eso lo copio y lo pego en la consola de PHPMyADMIN y me ejecuta la consulta perfectamente. Me inserta los datos. Desde PHP hago un `affected_rows` para saber si hay filas afectadas, me dice que si se afectaron filas, despues en la BD no aparece esas filas.

Porque puede ser?

**EDIT**

Hago varias consultas seguidas, pero las demás tablas e insert into funciona

NOTA--> Si ejecuto esta consulta:

`$consulta = "create  table orden_requisitos(NIA char(7),TOTAL tinyint unsigned)";
$objetoBBDD->consultarBD($consulta);`

Despues de la multiquery, la tabla orden_requisitos no me la crea, por eso la puse en primer lugar.

**Mi código PHP:**

```
$consulta = "create  table orden_requisitos(NIA char(7),TOTAL tinyint unsigned)";
$objetoBBDD->consultarBD($consulta);

$query1 = "create  table oferta_formacion(idOferta tinyint unsigned,idFormacion tinyint unsigned);";
$objetoBBDD->consultarBD($query1);

$query2 = "insert into oferta_formacion 
        select idOferta, requisito1
          from ofertas
        where idOferta=".$idOferta.";  

        insert into oferta_formacion 
        select idOferta, requisito2
          from ofertas
        where idOferta=".$idOferta.";  

        insert into oferta_formacion 
        select idOferta, requisito3
          from ofertas
        where idOferta=".$idOferta.";  

        insert into oferta_formacion 
        select idOferta, requisito4
          from ofertas
        where idOferta=".$idOferta."; 

        insert into oferta_formacion 
        select idOferta, requisito5
          from ofertas
        where idOferta=".$idOferta."; 

        insert into oferta_formacion 
        select idOferta, actitud1
          from ofertas
        where idOferta=".$idOferta."; 

        insert into oferta_formacion 
        select idOferta, actitud2
          from ofertas
        where idOferta=".$idOferta.";    

        insert into oferta_formacion 
        select idOferta, actitud3
          from ofertas
        where idOferta=".$idOferta.";";

$objetoBBDD->consultarBDMulti($query2); //<-- multiquery


$query4 = "INSERT INTO orden_requisitos (SELECT NIA, COUNT(*) AS Total FROM alumnos_formacion inner join oferta_formacion
        ON alumnos_formacion.idFormacion=oferta_formacion.idFormacion WHERE idOferta=".$idOferta." GROUP BY NIA 
        ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC);";
$objetoBBDD->consultarBD($query4);
```

Comment: Hola, podría ser de ayuda si agregas el código PHP en el que haces la consulta.

Comment: Parece tan simple como que olvidaste poner $query->execute(), pero sería de ayuda ver el código php.

Comment: No se entiende bien el planteamiento. Lo que sí hace pensar el leer tu pregunta es que tu modelo de datos necesita urgentemente ser rediseñado de otra forma más eficiente.